# SQL Server 2008 R2 Cluster with HOSTS file entries to active node on the application servers

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I questioned the decision of a colleague concerning the use of a HOSTS file entry on an application server (standard SQL database backed .NET solution), which I think would cause connections to the SQL Cluster to connect only a single node in the SQL Cluster.  In other words, the by using a HOSTS file entry like this....

```
10.10.0.100        SQLCLUSTER
```

...when the IP address above is the IP address of the active node in the SQL cluster and the application connection string contains SQLCLUSTER as the data source.

Intuitively, I would think the clustering technology would fail in an Active-Passive cluster configuration when using HOSTS files as described above.  I do not have in-depth knowledge of MS SQL clustering, just more traditional network load balancing.  Am I correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hosts file?!! I'm going to keep this short and sweet... you should be using **AD DNS**.

Clustering uses many facilties and one of the main requirements is an AD and DNS infrastructure. It uses this for many of its configurations and features. While in theory a hosts file *might* work with some hackery it's not best practice nor a supported configuration.

Comment: I know, I'm very concerned about the heavy use of HOSTS files on this project.

Answer (score 1):

It won't work. The SQL service will be listening on the cluster IP address, not the individual server's IP (unless you configure things to behave otherwise).